# Unity Android adding com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider to manifest when it shouldn't

Tags: android, facebook, android-studio, unity-game-engine, android-manifest

I'm developing a test app with some pretty basic functionality to prove a few concepts.  I do not have any Facebook plugins or SDKs included, nor do I want them.  I just want to test some Google Play services on an actual Android device.  However, when I build the apk, and run it from Android Studio, the AndroidManifest has a series of activity tags with references to com.facebook, and a provider named com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider.

If I deploy the apk to my device, I get this error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider
>   com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.DanGame.TestApp-KgL6Jybi9sG1Q0LHnxAnNA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.DanGame.TestApp-KgL6Jybi9sG1Q0LHnxAnNA==/lib/arm,
>   /data/app/com.DanGame.TestApp-KgL6Jybi9sG1Q0LHnxAnNA==/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a,
>   /system/lib]]

I could just bite the bullet and include the Facebook SDK, or try to manually adjust the manifest after it's generated.  But what I really need to know is how to get Unity to stop generating a bad manifest?  There has to be a way to build a functioning Android apk from Unity without Facebook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the issue was a caching problem.  I was building the APK in Unity and profiling it from Android Studio.  But Android Studio caches off the APK in the Users directory, so recompiling the apk in Unity will not reload the Android Studio project.  Even though I had cleared all references to Facebook from my manifest in Unity, Android Studio was using an old apk.